# Modifying TLS SNI with HttpClient or HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, https, sni

This question is the equivalent of [this Go question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250164/stripping-sni-information-from-tls-websocket-connections) in which it was trivial (albeit rather hacky) to obtain the desired behavior: I am looking for a way to modify the TLS SNI information that ultimately ends up in the TCP segments created when using the high-level web clients in .NET.

The final paragraph in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706609/5085211) suggests that a hack would be to do something like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://desiredsni.com");
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Host", "example.com");
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
    };
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
    }
}
```

to perform a request to desiredsni.com with a host of example.com and an SNI of desiredsni.com. Nevertheless, in my testing, and contrary to what is suggested by the answer, the SNI tag *is* changed to example.com, which is no good in my case, as what I want is really for the Host header field to be one thing, and the SNI field to be something else (and I'll settle for removing SNI entirely). Similarly, letting `httpRequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri("https://example.com");` also updates the SNI tag to example.com.

Is there a straightforward way to modify what ends up in the SNI field using `HttpClient`, `HttpWebRequest`, or something similar, without modifying anything else in the TCP segment?

Comment: Best guess is to dig deep into this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17852